# Jackson deserialize date from Twitter to `ZonedDateTime`

Tags: java, java-8, jackson, zoneddatetime

I want to deserialize date from Twitter to `ZonedDateTime`. My program fails on the `created_at` field deserializing.

My Domain class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public final class Tweet {

    public final String id;
    public final String idStr;
    public final ZonedDateTime created_at;
    public final String text;
    public final long timestamp_ms;
    public final User user;


    @JsonCreator
    public Tweet(@JsonProperty("id") String id,
                 @JsonProperty("id_str") String idStr,
                 @JsonProperty("created_at") ZonedDateTime created_at,
                 @JsonProperty("text") String text,
                 @JsonProperty("timestamp_ms") long timestamp_ms,
                 @JsonProperty("user") User user) {
        this.id = id;
        this.idStr = idStr;
        this.created_at = created_at;
        this.text = text;
        this.timestamp_ms = timestamp_ms;
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

My parsing approach

```
public class TweetTest {
    private static final String TWEET = "{\"created_at\":\"Mon Aug 20 13:28:07 +0000 2018\",\"id\":1031533339793129472,\"id_str\":\"1031533339793129472\",\"text\":\"juntar dinheiro pra ir na prox tour do justin bieber que eu amo\",\"source\":\"\\u003ca href=\\\"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/download\\/iphone\\\" rel=\\\"nofollow\\\"\\u003eTwitter for iPhone\\u003c\\/a\\u003e\",\"truncated\":false,\"in_reply_to_status_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_status_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id\":null,\"in_reply_to_user_id_str\":null,\"in_reply_to_screen_name\":null,\"user\":{\"id\":1239680360,\"id_str\":\"1239680360\",\"name\":\"ste\",\"screen_name\":\"flowxrst\",\"location\":\"Manaus, Brasil\",\"url\":null,\"description\":null,\"translator_type\":\"none\",\"protected\":false,\"verified\":false,\"followers_count\":1444,\"friends_count\":378,\"listed_count\":5,\"favourites_count\":13566,\"statuses_count\":40091,\"created_at\":\"Sun Mar 03 19:38:25 +0000 2013\",\"utc_offset\":null,\"time_zone\":null,\"geo_enabled\":true,\"lang\":\"pt\",\"contributors_enabled\":false,\"is_translator\":false,\"profile_background_color\":\"FFFFFF\",\"profile_background_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/abs.twimg.com\\/images\\/themes\\/theme1\\/bg.png\",\"profile_background_tile\":false,\"profile_link_color\":\"000000\",\"profile_sidebar_border_color\":\"FFFFFF\",\"profile_sidebar_fill_color\":\"DDEEF6\",\"profile_text_color\":\"333333\",\"profile_use_background_image\":false,\"profile_image_url\":\"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1030497329999237121\\/MLVfvoFy_normal.jpg\",\"profile_image_url_https\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/1030497329999237121\\/MLVfvoFy_normal.jpg\",\"profile_banner_url\":\"https:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_banners\\/1239680360\\/1533144133\",\"default_profile\":false,\"default_profile_image\":false,\"following\":null,\"follow_request_sent\":null,\"notifications\":null},\"geo\":null,\"coordinates\":null,\"place\":null,\"contributors\":null,\"is_quote_status\":false,\"quote_count\":0,\"reply_count\":0,\"retweet_count\":0,\"favorite_count\":0,\"entities\":{\"hashtags\":[],\"urls\":[],\"user_mentions\":[],\"symbols\":[]},\"favorited\":false,\"retweeted\":false,\"filter_level\":\"low\",\"lang\":\"pt\",\"timestamp_ms\":\"1534771687826\"}";

    @Test
    public void jackson_parsesDateTime() throws IOException {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
        mapper.setDateFormat(dateFormat);

        Tweet tweet = mapper.readValue(TWEET, Tweet.class);

        Assert.assertNotNull(tweet);
    }

    @Test
    public void ztd_parse() throws ParseException {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy");

        ZonedDateTime.parse("Mon Aug 20 13:28:07 +0000 2018", formatter);
    }
}
```

Both tests fail with the `om.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type`java.time.ZonedDateTime`from String "Mon Aug 20 13:28:07 +0000 2018": Text 'Mon Aug 20 13:28:07 +0000 2018' could not be parsed at index 0` error.

I've checked the similar questions on Stackoverflow, 
my `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy"` format looks correct.

That I'm doing wrong?

**SOLVED**

The problem was in the locale. After adding the exact locale tests started to pass.

for `jackson_parsesDateTime`

```
@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", locale = "en")
@JsonProperty("created_at") ZonedDateTime created_at,
```

for `ztd_parse` test

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add this annotation over your property

```
@JsonFormat(shape= JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy")
@JsonProperty("created_at") 
ZonedDateTime created_at;
```

Comment: `@JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", locale = "en")` I also added the exact locale and my test passed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems your `Locale` does not match, try use `Locale.ENGLISH`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

and

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: that's solved `ztd_parse` but `jackson_parsesDateTime` still fails.